# How do I check if certain text exists on a page (puppeteer)

Tags: node.js, xpath, puppeteer

Sorry in advance if I seem kinda clueless, I just started using puppeteer yesterday and I’m inexperienced with this kinda stuff.
I’m trying to check if a certain page (opened with puppeteer) has the phrase “hello” for example, keep in mind that I know the XPath of the text (if it exists). I’ve tried .waitForXPath() but I can’t seem to get it to work. Is there an easier function for this?

Comment: Can you show short but representative samples of the HTML, the XPath expression and the text, plus how your Node.js code looks and how it fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(await page.content()).match('hello')
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what you typed into `.waitforXPath()` method.

I can imagine this can work:

```js
await page.waitForXPath("//*[contains(text(), 'hello')]");
```

But it might be slow because all texts of all elements will be searched. It's better to narrow down the search to e.g. some elements. Unfortunately you don't provide more specifics, so I can't help you there.